# using join a table to itself and join another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables like below pictures :

users table :

[image]

offer_comments

[image]

`offer_comments` table stores comments and answer to comments.
by using below function I can get comments and answer to comments depending on `$id`.

```
function getCommentsAnItem($id){

    mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
    $result_comments = mysql_query("select e.comment as comment,m.comment as answer_to_comment 
    from offer_comments e 
    inner join offer_comments m on e.id = m.quet 
    where e.offer_id=$id and e.confirm=1");
    $comments = array();
    while($a_comment=mysql_fetch_object($result_comments)){

        $comment = array(
        'comment'=>$a_comment->comment,
        'answer'=>$a_comment->answer_to_comment
        );
        array_push($comments,$comment);
    }

    return $comments ;
}
```

How do I can get `name` and `family` from `users` table depending on `user_id` in `offer_comments` table ?

---

**updated:**

admin is where user_id equal = 1 .

`user_id 14690` is a user and leaves a comment and admin answer to him.

[image]

in the `users` table :
[image]

I would like to get an array of comments and answer to comments depending on $id :

```
"comment=>how a u ?","answer=> I am fine","comment.name=>name","comment.family=>family"
```

Answer (score 2):

Join your user table with your current query with `offer_comments` aliased as `m` so it will show the name and family of user who belongs to `m.comment` or the one who added `m.comment`,if you want to show the user of  `offer_comments` aliased as `e` then join on `e.user_id`

```
SELECT 
  e.comment AS `comment`,
  m.comment AS answer_to_comment,
  u.name,
  u.family 
FROM
  offer_comments e 
  INNER JOIN offer_comments m 
    ON e.id = m.quet 
  INNER JOIN users s 
    ON s.id = m.user_id 
WHERE e.offer_id = $id 
  AND e.confirm = 1
```

Comment: @S.M_Emamian Do you have user id against each comment ? and also change inner to left join for users table

Comment: 'Do you have user id against each comment ?' yes plz wait to update question.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian its better to provide your table structure and some sample data set @[*Sql Fiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) see [*Demo fiddle*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3333/5) how to put your structure and data